# How to display different form of data with single Model in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a function for api request as below

```
  func getUsers(completion:@escaping (Result<[ResultItem],NetworkError>) -> ()) {
        var uri = "";
        if(withID != ""){
          uri = "\test\withID"
        }

        
        else {
            uri = "\test"
        }
        
        let method = GET
        let urlString = "https:myownURL\(uri)"
        
//generates a header
        let urlHeader=headersGenerator()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlHeader) { [self] (data, response , error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Invalid JSON")

            do {
               let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self,from: data)
           
             completion(.success(results.userInfo))
            } catch {
             print("Error:\(error)")
          

            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Model is as follows

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let userInfo:[ResultItem]
}

struct ResultItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let userId: String
    var userlastname:String
    var username:String
}
```

This is giving me a proper response as below when I dont pass **withID**(the url will be https:myownURL.test )

The output is as below

```
{"userInfo":[{"userId":"0390","userlastname":"test1","username":"test1"},{"userId":"0391","userlastname":"test2","username":"test2"},{"userId":"0392","userlastname":"test3","username":"test3"}]}
```

But if i run the url with **withID**(the url will be https:myownURL.test.withID )
the output should give single value, and I am getting a single value but the format if different

```
{"userId":"0390","userlastname":"test1","username":"test1"}
```

but the model is same for both API so that it should return response as below

```
{"userInfo":[{"userId":"0390","userlastname":"test1","username":"test1"}]}
```

please let me know what mistake I am doing so that the response will come like this

```
{"userInfo":[{"userId":"0390","userlastname":"test1","username":"test1"}]}
```

I have provided complete reference code which I am using with proper URL and data, please help me on this

Comment: I think this is an issue of the api not you

Comment: both API returning the same data, just that one is giving a list and other is returning single data

Comment: @loremipsum you are right, the response from API is coming like that, need to handle it seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tell the API what result you want with the `withID` variable you can decode the data conditionally.

And it's recommended to call the `failure` case of `completion` on any error you get.

```
func getUsers(completion: @escaping (Result<[ResultItem],Error>) -> ()) {
    var uri = "\test"
    if !withID.isEmpty {
        uri += "\withID"
    } 
    
    let method = GET
    let urlString = "https:myownURL\(uri)"
    
    //generates a header
    let urlHeader = headersGenerator()
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlHeader) { (data, _ , error) in
        if let error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Invalid JSON")
        do {
            if !withID.isEmpty {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultItem.self,from: data!)
                completion(.success([results]))
            } else {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self,from: data!)
                completion(.success(results.userInfo))
            }
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: You read my mind, I was about to ask this question, Thanks a lot :)